# Counting number of Sales from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using SUM ( CASE WHEN ) to count number of Yes and No, it work fine.

I am havin problem counting number of matching mobile number from two tables. It dont seem to be counting correctly.

There is a `MobileNO` field in dairy table and `mobile` field in the sales table

```
SELECT 
       D.Username, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yes, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as No, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Other, 
       (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN D.MobileNo = S.mobile THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) from sales as S) as Sales, 
       COUNT(*) as TOTAL FROM dairy as D 
WHERE source = 'Company' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) >= 1293840000 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) <= 1322697600 
group by D.Username order by TOTAL DESC
```

Comment: How In what way is it not counting correctly?

Comment: @Mr E, See Parkyprg answer. It work fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
       D.Username, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yes, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as No, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Other, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN S.mobile IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Sales, 
       COUNT(*) as TOTAL 
FROM dairy as D 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT mobile FROM sales) as S ON D.MobileNo = S.mobile
WHERE source = 'Company' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) >= 1293840000 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) <= 1322697600 
group by D.Username order by TOTAL DESC
```